# How should I update Status field state in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I'm trying to implement a status field for Laravel Nova:

So, I have a job that takes 10 sec.

Here is my definition:

```
Status::make('Etat', 'job_state')
        ->loadingWhen(['waiting', 'running'])
        ->failedWhen(['failed']),
```

So, when my action triggers the job, I update the job state to `running`

```
$missingData->job_state = "running";
$missingData->update();
```

This is working.

But when the job ends, I update the field with:

```
$missingData->job_state = "finished";
$missingData->update();
```

but the state of the field will not update without a page refresh. Is it possible to change status field without refreshing ?

Answer (score 0):

Nova can update the records automatically, without refreshing the page. It's called polling, you can check the documentation here: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/resources/#resource-polling

Basically, you just have to enable polling:

```
/**
 * Indicates whether the resource should automatically poll for new resources.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
public static $polling = true;
```

Other attributes are just to customize a bit, like how often you would like to.